# Get the day number from a date

Tags: php, date

I want to get the day number of a date.

For example my date is: `2015-12-31`, it should return `365` and `2015-01-1` would be `1.`

How can I do that?

EDIT: `date('z')` does not work for me, I dont want the current date

Comment: Show us what you have tried, it'll make people more likely to help you.

Comment: Read the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and particularly the `z` format option.... yes, it starts from `0` for 1st January, but you can always add `1` to the result

Comment: I tried this but it gave me 2016 as result. is the format dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: Okay it worked, I did something wrong with an array

Comment: @Gintoki your format is Y-m-d btw

Comment: Just noticed that this is not what I am looking for, I dont want the current day

Comment: The date() function will work with any date (within PHP's date range).... not simply todays date..... RTFM and __look at the second argument__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$today = getdate(strtotime('2015-12-31'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($today['yday'] + 1);
?>
```

Read [GetDate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This worked, I just need need the [yday] from the array

Comment: I totally agree with you Jay @JayBlanchard and would indeed be informative for the OP and future visitors to the question/answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use strtotime() — to parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp. And getdate() — Get date/time information.

```
<?php
$day = getdate(strtotime("2015-12-31"));
echo $day['yday']+1; // output 365 
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Can you please add explanation to my this answer?

Comment: No, you should add the explanation. Click 'edit' and make the changes.

Comment: ok..can you please make it more better from your end?

Comment: That is not how this works @AmitRajput, others will not generally edit your questions to improve them. This is something you must do as you learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
<?php

$day = 31;
$mon = 12;
$year = 2015;
$sum = 0;
$days = 0;
$month_day = array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $mon; $i++){
    $sum += $month_day[$i];
}

$days = $sum - ($month_day[$mon-1] - $day);
echo "$days";



?>
```

You may get day, mon, year from your expected date and make it integer. You should check the year is leap year or not. It may vary one day if it is a leap year. I think you shall do it.